# Spring Framework 5 -How to stop entity setter methods from flushing changes to databases?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-framework-beans

I am working on migrating a project from spring framework 4 to 5.

**Spring Framework 4 Behavior:** In the older version of the project, if I changed the value of a managed entity object via its setter method hibernate would only flush to db if the changes were made within a @Transactional annotated method. Otherwise, the flush to db wouldn't ever happen.
For instance, the following changes will be flushed into db.

```java
    // Example 1
    @Transactional
    public void updateUser() {
        User user = userService.get(2L);
        user.setName("dummy");
    }
```

And the following changes won't get flashed to db.

```java
    // Example 2
    public void updateUser() {
        User user = userService.get(2L);
        user.setName("dummy");
    }
```

**Spring Framework 5 Behaviro:** But in spring framework 5 even if I change the value of a managed entity object via its setter method within a method that is not annotated with @Transactional, hibernate would flush the changes to db. If we consider the above examples both example 1 and 2 will flush the change to db.

I have searched in Stack Overflow about this issue and found that this is excepted behavior in the newer version according to the documentation. But my problem is that the project I am migrating is huge and it is not possible to search and change every file to mitigate this issue.

So I am searching for a solution to get back the old behavior of spring @Transactional annotation in the newer version of the spring framework which will only trigger the flush to db action only if the @Transactional annotation is defined on a method.

Comment: Hibernate can not magically flush changes when there is no transaction active. Set a break point there and look in the call stack where the transaction is started. You probably just misconfigured something.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianBeikov I was debugging the call stack and found out that because of an interceptor annotated with Transactional the readOnly transaction was getting merged with non readOnly transaction and it was because of that interceptor the non-annotated method changes were getting flushed to db.